# Alias [recommendation-system] and [recommendation-engine]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

From the tag wikis, I cannot see a difference between [recommendation-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-system) (272 questions) and [recommendation-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-engine) (1,225 questions). 68 questions are tagged with both.

I think these should be made synonyms.

[recommendation-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-engine) has the better tag wiki. I suggest to make this the synonym target.

These are small tags. It is hard to find enough people with enough reputation in either tag to create such a synonym. So the normal synonym process is not going to work.

Comment: Sounds pretty clearly reasonable.  I'll create it in a couple days if no one objects.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system) seems to think they're all synonyms. (And recommender as well as recommendation.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now done.

A synonym was created from [recommendation-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-system) to [recommendation-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-engine), and the tags were merged.

A previously existing synonym for [recommender-systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommender-systems) to [recommendation-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-system) was also replaced with one targeting [recommendation-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-engine) instead.

> System or engine?
> Distinction without difference.
> The tags are now merged.